# Difficulty in understanding the proof of infinitude of primes in a certain arithmetic progression

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $m$ as a fixed odd prime. How to show there are infinitely many primes of the form $2km+1$ (for some positive integer $k$).

Can someone please help? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are given all the relevant links.

Comment: But I can't find those in internet.

Comment: So try a library.

Comment: These seem to be proofs there are infinitely many primes of a certain structure, not proofs that there are infinitely many primes (as the title of this question suggests).

Comment: Lebesgue's one is [here](https://archive.org/details/s1journaldemat08liou/page/50/mode/2up), page 50. Landry's proof I think it is a simple consequence.

Comment: Genocchi's is [here](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Annali_di_matematica_pura_ed_applicata/pOx-l4rLW-UC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=genocchi+"intorno+ad+un+teorema+di+cauchy"&pg=PA216&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: Dickson is just giving a summary of the ideas in the proofs, not necessarily enough for someone to reconstruct the full proofs. For that, Dickson expects you to consult the sources.

Comment: Thanks @michael

Comment: @michael I have fixed the title .now look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only one written out with sufficient detail for me to reverse-engineer the proof is the Landry one.  Here is my take on it (in English):

First fix $m$ as an odd prime. We will show there are infinitely many primes of the form $2km+1$ (for some positive integer $k$). Assume there are only finitely many (we reach a contradiction). Let $\theta$ be the largest one.  Let $x$ be the product of all primes of the form $2km+1$. Then

- Claim 1:  $x^m+1$ is not divisible by any primes of the form $2km+1$.
- Claim 2: $\frac{x^m+1}{x+1}$ is a positive integer.
- Claim 3: All prime divisors of $\frac{x^m+1}{x+1}$ are of the form $2km+1$.

Assuming these three claims:  From Claim 1 and 2 it follows that the integer $\frac{x^m+1}{x+1}$ is not divisible by any primes of the form $2km+1$. So $\frac{x^m+1}{x+1}$ must be divisible by some prime that is *not* of the form $2km+1$. But this contradicts Claim 3. $\Box$

---

**Proof of Claim 1:** Let $z$ be a prime of the form $2km+1$. By construction, $x^m$ is divisible by $z$. Thus,  $x^m+1$ cannot be divisible by $z$.

**Proof of Claim 2:** We have for any real number $y$: 
$$ (1+y+y^2+...+y^{m-1})(1-y) = 1-y^m$$
Choosing $y=-x$ (where $-x$ is an integer) gives 
$$ \underbrace{(1+(-x) +(-x)^2 + ... + (-x)^{m-1})}_{integer}(1+x)=1-(-x)^m = 1+x^m$$
where the final equality holds because $m$ is odd, so $(-1)^m=-1$.

**Proof of Claim 3:** I don't know.  But, nothing in the above has used the assumption that $m$ is prime (we have only used that $m$ is an odd positive integer). So, Claim 3 must somehow use the assumption that $m$ is prime.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can anyone help how to prove claim 3?

Comment: Michael, math_is_fun has posted [a question about Claim 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3699278/1508), without mentioning the connection to anybody. I thought you might like to know.

Comment: I have asked that question separately@Michael. In the following [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3699278/all-prime-divisors-of-fracxm1x1-are-of-the-form-2km1). Kindly have a look .

Comment: Thanks.  The context of the Dickson reference (in the original question) seems to have disappeared, which also makes it hard to know what the first line of my answer above  is referring to (that line mentions Landry).  By the way, I do not understand the hostility to this question or why people grouped up to close it.

Comment: Me too..that is why I had to update the question..please vote to reopen it.

Comment: The following link provides the Dickson reference that was in the original question: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L15aA.jpg In particular, Dickson writes the following 3 sentences (my answer is an attempt to fill in the details based on these 3 sentences): "F. Landry gave a proof like Lebesgue’s.  If $\theta$ is the
largest prime $2km+1$ and if $x$ is the product of all of them, $x^m+1$ is divisible by no one
of them.  Since $(x^m+1)/(x+1)$ has no prime divisor not of the form $2km+1$, there exists
at least one $>\theta$."