# All prime divisors of $\frac{x^m+1}{x+1}$ are of the form $2km+1$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $m$ be an odd prime and $x$ be the product of all primes of the form $2km+1$. Then all prime divisors of $\frac{x^m+1}{x+1}$ are of the form $2km+1$.

What I know is that $\frac{x^m+1}{x+1}$ is an integer.

Here is the [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3698851/difficulty-in-understanding-the-proof-of-infinitude-of-primes-in-a-certain-arith/3698899#3698899) to the answer which prompted this question.

Can anyone help me how to prove this.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know if your $x$ is finite sum or infinite being a product of all prime of the form your mentioned.

Comment: You _really_ should have provided a link to [the answer that prompted this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3698899/1508). Firstly, you are doing Michael a disservice; secondly, you are depriving all of us the motivation for your question.

Comment: @TonyK I have added the link.

Comment: In case anyone doesn't notice the link in the question:  Of course $x=\infty$, as there are infinitely many primes of that form.  This question is really the middle of a proof trying to _prove_ there are infinitely many, and so it should be assumed (for the sake of contradiction) that $x$ is finite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $2 \nmid \frac{x^m+1}{x+1}$. Let odd prime $p$ divide $\frac{x^m+1}{x+1}$ :

**Case $1$ :**  $m \mid (p-1)$

We clearly have $p=mq+1$ for some $q \in \mathbb{N}$. As $p$ is an odd prime, $mq+1$ is odd, and thus, $mq$ is even. Moreover, $m$ is an odd prime, thus, $q=2k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Substituting:
$$p=2km+1$$
which proves that our prime divisor is of the required form.

---

**Case $2$ :** $m \nmid (p-1)$

We have:
$$p \mid (x^m+1) \implies p \mid(x^{2m}-1) \implies p \mid(x^{\gcd(2m,p-1)}-1)$$
by Fermat's Little Theorem.

Since $m$ is an odd prime not dividing $p-1$, it follows:
$$\gcd(2m,p-1)=\gcd(2,p-1)=2$$
This shows us that $p \mid (x^2-1)$.

We thus either have $p \mid (x-1)$ or $p \mid (x+1)$.

**Subcase $1$ :** $p \mid (x-1)$

We have:
$$p \mid (x-1) \implies p \mid (x^m-1)$$
Since $p \mid (x^m+1)$, it follows that $(x^m+1)-(x^m-1)=2$ is also divisible by $p$ which is a contradiction as $p$ is an odd prime.

**Subcase $2$ :** $p \mid (x+1)$

This is the same as $x \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$. But then:
$$\frac{x^m+1}{x+1} \equiv x^{m-1}-x^{m-2}+\cdots+1 \equiv 1-(-1)+1-(-1)+\cdots+1 \equiv m \pmod{p}$$

As $p \mid \frac{x^m+1}{x+1}$, it follows that $p \mid m$. Since $p$ and $m$ are both odd primes, we must thus have $p=m$.

However:
$$p \mid (x^m+1) \implies m \mid (x^m+1)$$
Note that as all the prime factors of $x$ are $1 \pmod{m}$, we have $x \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$. Then:
$$0 \equiv x^m+1 \equiv 1+1 \equiv 2 \pmod{m} \implies m \mid 2$$
and this is once again a contradiction since $m$ is an odd prime.

---

Thus, we have proved that all prime divisors of $\frac{x^m+1}{x+1}$ are of the form $2km+1$.

Comment: Why is 2 clearly a prime factor of $\frac{x^m+1}{x+1}$?

Comment: It seems to me that if $m$ is odd and $x$ is an integer (with $x \neq -1$)  then 
$$\frac{1+x^m}{1+x} = 1 + \underbrace{(-x) + (-x)^2 + … + (-x)^{m-1}}_{\mbox{even number of terms}} = odd$$

Comment: Ah sorry, that is my bad :) I have made the required edit.

Answer (score 0):

As  $x$ is product of all primes of the form $2km+1$ it's also of this form. So, $x^m+1$ isn of this form $2Km+2$. Means $2m \nmid x^m+1$ as $m>2$.

If some prime $p >2, p \nmid {x+1}$ divides $\frac{x^m+1}{x+1}$, it also divides $x^m+1$.

So, $x^m \equiv -1 (\text{mod} p)$

or, $x^{2m} \equiv 1 (\text{mod} p)$.

Also, as $p|x^m+1, \text{gcd}(p, x)=1$

This implies that $x^{p-1} \equiv 1 (\text{mod} p)$. ( From Fermat's little theorem)

$\big [$ There doesn't exist any $2<r<2m$ such that $x^r \equiv 1 (\text{mod} p)$. Otherwise $r|2m \rightarrow r|m$. But $m$ is a prime.

Also $p \nmid x^2-1$ as $p \nmid x+1$. Because if some prime $q|x+1$, $q \nmid \frac{x^m+1}{x+1}$ ....(0) $\big ]$

$\Big ($ Proof to (0): If $q|(x+1)$ then , $x \equiv -1(\text{mod} q)$ (surely $q$ can't be equal to $m$).

Now, $A=\frac{x^m+1}{x+1}=x^{m-1}-x^{m-2}+.....+(-1)^{m-2}1$ As, $m$ is odd prime, $A \equiv m (\text{mod} q)$. If  $A$ is divisible by $q$, then $q|m$. But that's impossible as $m$ is  an odd prime. $\Big)$

> Hence, $2m|(p-1) \rightarrow p=2km+1$ for some $k \in \mathbb N$

Also the  case that $p-1|2m$ isn't possible being $m>1$ a prime and $p \geq 3$.

So all the prime factors dividing $\frac{x^m+1}{x+1}$ is of the form $2km+1$.

Comment: I believe your answer is incomplete. How is it direct that $q \mid (x+1) \implies q \nmid \frac{x^m+1}{x+1}$? Shouldn't the explanation for that be given?

Comment: Because that requires $q|m$. As $m$ is a prime It's not possible. Also  $q≠m$, otherwise $q \nmid (x+1)$ Doesn't follow the starting assumption ( Because $x \equiv 1(\text{mod} m)$ $ m>2$).

Comment: Yes, that is what I had written in my answer. It is better if that explanation is given ig :)

Comment: Why $x^m+1$ isn't of this form means $2m \nmid x^m+1$? @alapan das

Comment: Because it's given that $x$ is the product of all $(2km+1)$ type primes.  Thai means $x^m+1$ is of $2mK+2$ form, which definetly isn't divisible by$2m$.